# How to write a script that will use regex to output only the heading and paragraph text from the http://example.com website

Tags: bash, curl, awk, grep

I am a beginner in scripting and i am working on the bash scripting for my work.

for this task i tried the sed command which didn't work

Comment: Welcome to SO, as already mentioned by dash-o in above comment too; please do always add 3 simple things in your question(s). 1st- Sample of input, 2- sample of output and 3rd- Efforts which you have put in order to solve your own problem. Also check Search functionality of SO which is a GREAT tool to search/look for questions too, if it is a basic question I am pretty sure you will get answer there itself, cheers. BTW I am voting to close this Question until I see you added mentioned details in your post, fyi.

Answer (score 0):

for your problem, following would work:

```
#!/bin.bash
curl -s http://example.com/ | grep -P "\s*\<h1\>.*\<\/h1\>" |sed -n 's:.*<h1>\(.*\)</h1>.*:\1:p'
curl -s http://example.com/ | grep -P "\s*\<p\>.*\<\/p\>" |sed -n 's:.*<p>\(.*\)</p>.*:\1:p'
```

The first line scrapes via curl and grep the `<h1>..</h1>` part(assuming theres only one as we are considering your example) and using sed extract the first capturing group`( (.*) )` by `:\1:`

The second line does the same but for `<p1>` tag.
I could cram these 2 lines in one grep but these'll work fine!

**Edit:**

If `<p>` tag end on different lines, above wouldn't, you may have to use `pcregrep`

```
curl -s http://example.com/ | pcregrep -M  "\s*\<p\>(\n|.)*\<\/p\>"
```

Comment: Sorry for the typo, did it in a rush during work. and Noted your advice, ty.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following one liner :

```
curl -s http://example.com/ | sed -n '2,$p'  > /tmp/tempfile  && cat /tmp/tempfile | xmllint --xpath '/html/head/title/text()' - &&  echo ; cat /tmp/tempfile | xmllint --xpath '/html/body/div/p/text()' -
```

This uses xmllint's xpath command to extract the text within `<title>` and `<p>` tags.